# Home Range/ Kernel Density using Quadrats, not GPS

Tags: open-source, data-analysis

I am interested in calculating territory size and location for small marine organisms. They dwell in small structures from 50-250mm2. I would be using video to record 2D movements, and would tag their location within a quadrat at specific time intervals (ex: every 30 sec). Since their dwellings are so small, I will not GPS their different movements as their dwellings is equivalent to the size of small coral heads (for your easy reference). Can you please suggest what software/package/program(s) to use to run kernel density home range analysis? I have used adehabitatHR in R for large scale GPS-positioned territory analysis, but GPS is simply not accurate for my new study species.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! On what OS should that software run, and what is your price margin if it comes to paid solutions?